# How to access the Quick Link / Admin Menu in Windows 8 using touch?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, windows-rt

In Windows 8.0 and Windows RT you can right-click in the bottom-left corner to access a [menu](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/win8-tips-tricks,review-1778-4.html) of commonly used desktop links.  You can access the same menu with the keyboard using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Is there a way to access this menu using touch?

I have a Surface RT and have tried a number of gestures in the corner (e.g., press and hold, swipe down) on both the Desktop and the Start Screen without any luck.

**EDIT:** This issue is fixed in Windows 8.1 and Windows RT 8.1.  You can press and hold on the reinstated Start button to access the Quick Link menu.

Comment: I would look for ways to do a right click in Windows 8.... Does long pressing with one finger and then tapping with another do anything? (I don't have a Win8 Touch device to test with)

Comment: Thanks @BryanDenny. The usual substitute for right click on the desktop is a long press, but is always treated as a taskbar right click.  On the start screen it's a downward swipe which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible.

I also tried a scenario where you would would simulate the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> keystroke using AutoIt software (you could make an executable file with the script), but it seems that the  <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> combination is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring up all apps and select On-Screen Keyboard, its different than the default keyboard and spoarts a Win key so you can win x.  Not a great option because that keyboard is not default but in a pinch it does work.

You can always pin the other keyboard to your taskbar and use it when needed. that is fairly quick to open it that way.
K.

Comment: That works! Although I find it a bit fiddly for accessing a 'quick' link menu.  If in touch only mode I think I'll be using the Search charm, which is more natural to me after more 'metro' exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold to [right-click](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-touch-gestures).

Comment: unfortunately this just brings up the context menu for the taskbar rather than Quick Links / Admin menu.